# Why is Lone Starr's ship called the Eagle 5?

Tags: spaceballs

Per the Spaceballs [wiki article](http://spaceballs.wikia.com/wiki/Eagle_5) on the subject

> Eagle 5 is the 1986 Winnebago Chieftain 33 that Lone Starr and Barf
>   travel in, using it as a flying spaceship (with space engines and
>   wings attached)

[image]

**But why is it called the Eagle 5?** Am I missing the joke somehow?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/1vb29f/til_bill_pullmans_call_sign_in_independence/

Comment: Pure speculation: [Eagle One](http://catacombs.space1999.net/main/merc/vmmemattel.html) is the name of a ship from [Space:1999](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagle_Transporter). Perhaps there was also an Eagle Five?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Luke Skywalker had a call sign of ***"Red 5"*** when he flew a X-Wing in the Red Squadron, in the Battle of Yavin, to destroy the Death Star, in A New Hope.

Han Solo Piloted the ***"Millennium Falcon"***.

Lone Starr is a parody of both Luke and Han. Hence, **"Eagle 5"**. It does play both the role of the Falcon and the X-Wing throughout the movie.

Comment: This seems very plausible +1

Comment: Also, "The Eagle has landed"

Comment: Also Millennium is 1000, so 5 is the cut-down budget version...

Comment: This seems to be the best overall answer, but how is it that no one has mentioned the Eagle lander from Apollo 11?

Comment: @Omegacron What did Zommuter do?

Comment: @Yakk I mean in an answer. Zommuter's comment had been on here for 5 hours before I said anything. I'd rather see it added to this existing answer than create my own, so I was pointing it out.

Comment: @Omegacron there is no the eagle has landed joke in the transcript

Comment: @cde - no, but the Eagle was the name of the lunar lander module on the Apollo 11 mission, and Armstrong famously said "Houston, the Eagle has landed" when they touched down. It has a famous association with space travel, and "Eagle 5" is doubtless a nod to it. Your answer is correct, but it doesn't say where the "Eagle" part of "Eagle 5" comes from.

Comment: @Omegacron I'm guessing its a lot less though out parody than you think. The best jokes tend to be the simplest. SOLO becomes LONE, Skywalker was originally Starkiller. The Eagle is just another bird closely related to Falcons

Comment: Well, when they were crashing on Yogurt's planet, Lonestar does say "Eagle 5, coming in" which is close. At any rate, just thought I'd point it out.

Comment: @cde "going to warp" turned into "going to warp and weft", which (if they are different colors) is plaid, so ludicrous speed is "going to plaid" -- I think you underestimate the tortured references of SpaceBalls.

Comment: @Yakk, that's all speculation from http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/95506/16696, specifically Praxis.

Comment: @cde Mel Brooks is the single most prolific movie parody director of our time. (If you can think of anyone even close, please say so.) Regardless of the exact speculation, to say there isn't much thought going on in the writing of is, for lack of a better word, ludicrous.

Answer (score 12):

I figured it was multifaceted, consisting of:

1. Luke Skywalker being "Red 5" in the attack on the original Death Star in the first Star Wars film.
2. "[Eagles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagle_Transporter)" from Space 1999, which were a transporter and the primary way people moved around in that show. Mel Brooks [was "a dear, dear friend" of Barbara Bain and Martin Landau](http://catacombs.space1999.net/press/wrefpsuperstar.html), who were the stars of that show, at the time they were in it (and presumably still is):

   > "Let me tell you this story," continued Barbara. "The girls got used to seeing us on our television set. And Mel Brooks, who's a dear, dear friend of ours, invited us over with the children one night. He was on his television set. The girls actually grew up thinking that it was normal. We were on our television set, Mel was on his television set, then everyone must be on their own television."
3. A joke about the Millenium Falcon (for those for whom English is not your native language: Falcons and Eagles are both birds, and in fact both are birds of prey).

Here's a WP picture of an Eagle:

[image: Space 1999 Eagle Transporter]

Comment: I like this answer. I'm not so sure about the Space 1999 reference, though.

Comment: @Richard: Whereas I think it's just pathetic I know the transporters in Space 1999 were called Eagles. :-)

Comment: @Richard: You inspired me. :-)

Comment: I wish I had a second upvote

Comment: Nice answer, @T.J.Crowder.

Answer (score 6):

With all the "Star Wars" gags I would think it is a play on "Millennium Falcon" and the X-wing call signs Red 2, Gold leader, Red 6, etc but I have never seen or heard an actual explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I would think this is a reference to the lunar module "Eagle" on the Apollo 11 mission which was the first lunar landing.  The Eagle has landed!
[image]

Comment: Are there any sources that suggest this?

Comment: The eagle in the logo on the side of the ship looks very similar to this eagle, except it's holding green stacks of money instead of a tree branch. And the earth over the eagle's head is a circle with a '5' in it. https://i.imgur.com/YsOu0rY.png. The name could be inspired by 'Red 5', and the logo inspired by this.